# Why would terrestrial, rodent-sized sapient mammals evolve to be hairless?

Tags: evolution

Something of a sister question to the one posed on [biology sx](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/104605/why-did-the-naked-molerat-lose-its-fur). Assuming Earth-like conditions and biology in the realm of what has been observed in nature, what could possibly be worth losing a valuable insulating layer? While there are many examples of furless land animals (insects, reptiles & amphibians) on that scale, the vast majority of them are [ectotherms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ectotherm) and do not face the same challenges in maintaining their core temperature as mammals do. This is because mammals are (primarily) [endotherms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endotherm) and under the square-cube law, smaller animals must radiate heat "more effectively" than a comparable one of larger scale.

This ["list"](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83/how-to-deal-with-list-questions) question is posed largely to help worldbuilders in justifying tiny humanoids for their settings, although the scope easily(?) extends to all mammalian body plans. I will accept the first question that gives a substantial and evidence-based advantage to hairlessness at this scale.

Comment: There are quite a few breeds of [hairless dogs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairless_dog), some natural, some selected by humans. There are also [hairless bats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairless_bat), and of course the famous [naked mole-rats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naked_mole-rat). (And fur is specific to mammals, anyway. *All* reptiles and amphibians are furless.)

Comment: And to build on @AlexP's statement, there are also naked primates... we call them "humans." Otherwise, VTC as too broad. We need to convert this from an off-topic [infinite list of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6139/40609) to an on-topic [finite list of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6138/40609). My biggest problem is that every item on the list is intrinsically speculation and the "issue" is so broad (evolutionary pressures) and yet about an attribute so specific (hair) that I can't see a practical value to future worldbuilders.

Comment: To point out a fundamental part of my concern: a creature could lose its hair by migrating to a warmer climate where it's no longer needed to warm the body. Except that there are examples of both hairless and haired creatures in those climates. I don't believe any proposed reason can be anything other than a guess because the actual reason for any specific species will be unique to that species.

Comment: @join-jbh-on-codidact I think the key difference here is that the majority (perhaps I am incorrect?) of naturally furless mammals are "large". Humans, rhinos, elephants, hippos, seals, cetaceans, babirusa, and even hairless dogs. To my knowledge, only naked mole-rats and those hairless bats AlexP brought up defy the trend. Sphinx breeds do not count in my opinion. RE: value, almost every race (some are non-mammalian or artificial, to be fair) of fairies and borrowers fall under this umbrella. That aside, I do agree I went into this assuming there are a finite set of universal principles.

Answer (score 3):

Mammals evolve to be hairless, we did, mole rats did, there are others.

Mammals can also evolve to be sapient, we did.

Doesn't have to happen together or in any particular order.

You want an intelligent hairless mammal, clearly you can have one.

Why did *mole rats* lose their fur?

Maybe it got in the way in tight tunnels (caught on roots & such) & they just don't really need it to keep warm down there.

Dolphins & all other aquatic mammals lost there's as well, likely because it would be responsible for drag & a hindrance to swimming (so there's another option for you, say they had an aquatic phase then came back to the land), we probably lost ours to provide more efficient cooling which helps us keep going longer, Elephants have none, with their size they need to lose rather than conserve heat (so you might say they were big then shrank due to changing environmental circumstances, maybe a population got stuck on an island, which has been known to lead to reduced size in populations).

Once lost it doesn't have to come back when they need it, other methods like blubber can develop instead, or they might start wearing clothes if you've made them intelligent by then.

I'm sure you can come up with plenty of other reasons if you stop & think about it.

Comment: To spell out another interesting possibility your post raises: it could be that the ancestor species was larger and benefitted from furlessness, and retained that trait as it got smaller.

WRT naked molerats, do you have a source for your claim that snagging lead to their furlessness? Can you explain why this does not hold true for other burrowing mammals like meerkats? If you do, I would be happy to accept it over at biology sx.

Comment: *"do you have a source for your claim that snagging lead to their furlessness?"* No it's just a supposition, they are so there has to be a reason, that & they don't really need fur to keep warm in their burrows.

Answer (score 2):

**Frame Challenge!** to myself?

As suggested over at biology sx, *it is entirely possible there is no advantage*. The genes for fur may conflict with the genes for an even more valuable adaptation, which you as the author can pick freely. It could also be that the environment is consistently warm enough for them to adopt [heterothermic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterothermic) traits like the [sloth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sloth#Physiology) and [naked mole-rat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naked_mole-rat#Metabolism_and_respiration) that reduces the need for fur.

Comment: Good point, we don't really know, so it's "pick your preferred explanation" - or none at all. That one over at [biology.se] had stood out to me too, frankly this is as good an answer as you're likely to get there.